# How to write the contents of a csv file into an email using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a code that calculates a set of values and writes them into a csv file. I have been sending this csv file as an attachment in an email.

Now, I want to actually write the contents of the csv file on the email body itself rather than sending it as an attachment.

CSV file looks like this:

```
Region,Count
Asia,5
America,3
Europe,4
```

The code I have been using to send the email looks like this:

```
require 'mail'
def mailsender
  Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp,{ address: "smtp.xyz.com",openssl_verify_mode: "none" }
  end

  Mail.deliver do
    from     'abc@xyz.com'
    to       'admins@xyz.com'
    subject  'Status Report'
    body     'Please find attached the status report'
    add_file 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Ruby\Summary.csv'
  end
end
```

So instead of having an attached csv file with the information in it, I would like my mail body to look like:

Please find the summary below:

Asia     5
America  3
Europe   4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result it is enough if you concatenate current body
with a CSV data:

```
def formatted_body
  title + data.join("\n")
end
```

where title is a your current body and data values used to build CSV file

```
def title
  "Please find attached the status report:\n"
end

def data
  # code which returns your structure 
  ["Asia 5", "America 3", "Europe 4"]  

  # alternatively reuse existing .csv
  read_csv
end
```

In case you want to reuse existing .csv file

```
def read_csv
  content = CSV.read("data.csv")
  content.shift  # to exclude headers
  content.map {|row| row.join(' ') }
end
```

You might consider wrapping it into the class:

```
require 'mail'

class MailSender
  attr_accessor :data

  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end

  def mailsender
    Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp,{ address: "smtp.xyz.com",openssl_verify_mode: "none" }
    end

    Mail.deliver do
      from     'abc@xyz.com'
      to       'admins@xyz.com'
      subject  'Status Report'
      body     formatted_body
      add_file 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Ruby\Summary.csv'
    end
  end

  private 
  def formatted_body
    title + data.join("\n")
  end

  def title 
    "Please find attached the status report:\n"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stdlib's `CSV` to read the file:

```
require 'csv'

contents = CSV.read('file.csv')
```

which will give you an array of arrays, where the first value is the headers. You can also pass `headers: true` to get your values as hashes:

```
> contents = CSV.read('file.csv', headers: true)
> contents.first

 {
  "Region" => "Asia",
  "Count" => "5"
 }
```

This option is useful if you're dealing with larger datasets and need to access values by name:

```
> contents.map{|i| "#{i["Region"]} #{i["Count"]}"}

[
    [0] "Asia 5",
    [1] "America 3",
    [2] "Europe 4"
]
```

You can then `.join("\n")` these to get the string formatting you want.

Be careful with `CSV#read` as it pulls the entire file into memory. If it's a huge file, you can iterate over it line by line with `CSV#foreach`.